# How can I fix dep ensure error 'cannot stat file' on Mac?

Tags: go, dependencies, vendor

When running `dep ensure` on a large project it fails with the following error:

```
cannot Stat: stat <project>/vendor/github.com/prometheus/procfs/fixtures/self/fd/0: no such file or directory
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: The proper "fix" is to use dep no longer.

Comment: I had to do this while rebasing changes in a fork on a new upstream release - it's not really under my control.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are [known](https://github.com/golang/dep/issues/1625) [issues](https://github.com/golang/dep/issues/2024) with `dep` 0.5 (latest at this time) which cause the error. There's no fix yet, but you can downgrade to 0.4 to get things working.

You can use the install script in the project repo and specify the desired version through an environment variable.

```
export DEP_RELEASE_TAG="v0.4.1"
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/golang/dep/master/install.sh | sh
```